# CURL to nodeJS conversion no output

Tags: node.js

I am running a service and doing this CURL command which works fine - outputting a JSON reply

```
curl 'localhost:5000/parse?q=hello&model=MY_MODEL_PATH' | python -m json.tool
```

But when I convert this CURL to nodeJS code below, it is not returning any output. The program just exists. What am I missing?

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'localhost:5000/parse?q=hello&model=MY_MODEL_PATH'
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add "http" or "https"

var request = require('request');

```
var options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/parse?q=hello&model=MY_MODEL_PATH'
};
```